# Slow Parse requests with php

Tags: php, parse-platform

I have an issue with Parse requests.

I'm using a website to show all the stats of my IOS app. So I make requests from Parse using PHP to get stats of the app in real time. 
The page loading of my website are very slow though. I have to wait like 1 real minute to load a single page. I'm hosting my website on a private heroku server. 
Plus, my Parse dashboard is not as slow as my website.
I heard someone say that Parse have requests limits... ? Is it true ?

I make my requests like this:

```
$query = new ParseQuery("Categories")
$query->descending("createdAt");
echo($query->count()); // I use my query data instead of this
```

Sometimes, I use many requests on the same table. For example :

```
$query = new ParseQuery("Relations");
$query2 = new ParseQuery("Relations");
$query3 = new ParseQuery("Relations");
```

I do this because I have to select different columns from those queries. I didn't find a way to save a query in a variable. I wish I could to this:

```
$query = new ParseQuery("Relations");
$query2 = $query;
$query3 = $query;
```

I would increase my website performances but it's impossible...

Any idea?

**Edit:** 
here is a Chrome network inspection of one of my page. Look at the schelude time...

[image: Chrome network inspection screenshot]

Comment: There are no request limits on self hosted Parse server. You might face these issues for all sort of reasons, like badly written queries, lack of indexes in your database,  latency between the Parse Server and database, ect

Comment: Second lack of indexes. Parse.com used to automatically create indexes in mlab for you to help optimize queries. With parse-server, you are responsible for your own database management, which includes creating indexes to optimize your queries. You need to add an index for createdAt to your Categories collection.